# Adding chinese input to Gboard keyboard

Tags: gboard, input-methods, chinese-language

How do I enable chinese input to Gboard keyboard? I already have Google Pinyin Input enabled, but when I try to add a keyboard to Gboard, Chinese doesn't show up. When I long click on the keyboard to switch languages, nothing else shows up either.

Answer (score 2):

3/16/18 update -
Chinese has been added to the supported languages in the latest version.

Original answer -
Chinese is not supported in GBoard yet (as of 2/20). Neither are other East Asian languages such as Japanese and Korean. There's rumor that it'll be added in the upcoming versions.

For a full up-to-date list of languages supported, refer to this link -
https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/6380730#languages